# Где будет меньше перестановок : в сортировке пузырьком или методом выбора?

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, пузырьковая-сортировка

Где будет меньше перестановок : в сортировке пузырьком или методом выбора? И почему?

Answer (score 3):

Именно перестановок - в выборе, и это очевидно: там при перестановке элемент становится на свое место и больше не "бегает" (т.е. O(n) раз), а вот при пузырьке такие обмены идут постоянно, чтоб элемент стал на свое место ("пузырек всплыл"), может потребоваться n перестановок.

Итого O(n^2) раз - по сути, в худшем случае могут идти при каждом сравнении.